# How can I read specific data in my exel sheet and create a plot from each dataset that is read? (Python)

Tags: python, r, pandas

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

import csv 


file = r'C:\Users\Tiago Costa\Desktop\Senior Year - 2019.2020\ME 130\Coronovirus Datasets\time_series_2019-ncov-Confirmed.xlsx'

data = pd.ExcelFile(file)

print(data.sheet_names)

['Worksheet']

df = data.parse('Worksheet')

df.info

df.head(483)
```

I was wondering how I would be able to only extract the number of confirmed cases for China, Italy, Germany, Iran and USA, and then plot that data as a function of time.

I was going to be using this: https://pythonprogramming.net/loading-file-data-matplotlib-tutorial/  as a reference to create my plots when I got to that point.

Thank you!

Comment: can you please show us the sample of original (raw) data ?

Comment: The dataset can be found here:https://data.humdata.org/dataset/novel-coronavirus-2019-ncov-cases . It is under data and resources as the first file, I have then converted the CSV file to an XLSX file.

Comment: Not sure how to show all raw data through a comment or post here, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to convert it into `.xlsx` file first, because we can use [`.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). Then you can use [`.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) to filter which countries you want to take.

```
data = pd.read_csv('time_series_2019-ncov-Confirmed.csv')

countries = ['China', 'Italy', 'Germany', 'Iran', 'USA']
filtered_data = data[data['Country/Region'].isin(countries)]
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to extract the data with this method. Will the link I posted as a reference to plotting the dataset have enough information for me to be able to configure a graph? I am having trouble doing so as I am new to python.